# Linux network random hang Intel NUC

Tags: linux

Any version of current Linux;
Intel NUC with built in R8169 network, plus tried external USB network adaptor;

The interface will randomly stop sending/receiving with no errors in any logs.

ifconfig will show the interface as still active and connected. The lights on the RJ45 still flash.

I have found that running a ping from another machine will drop, that is when I know it has gone down. I have found that I can bring it back up by sending a ping from the affected machine. It pauses for a few seconds and then starts a successful ping. But again, after a few minutes it will go down again.

The is nothing obvious in the logs. In fact, as it goes up and down, there are no logs...

I've just run tcpdump on the machine and I can see network traffic??? I even see dns queries and ARP replies???

What I know for sure, communications resumes only if I initiate it from the affected machine. There are no routes, just a flat network and a 1GB netgear non managed switch.

when I type route and the network is working, I get an instant response. when the problem occurs, the command route takes 10-15 seconds to respond, however it is the same list.

If I pull the network cable and reconnect, the problem resolves, but returns after a few minutes.

This has been driving me crazy for over a year now.

*Edit

I have found what happens when the problems start. An ARP request is sent from the machine asking for Who has _gateway, which is the ip address of the internet router. I will remove the default route for now to see if it is the router not replying that is causing the network to hang, just on Linux on NUCs?

*Edit

Removing the default route does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found the problem. I have amazon devices on the network, Alexa, Kindles and fire sticks. one of those must be using the same address as this machine as watching a tcpdump from another machine showed this.

22:53:37.332273 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.100 is-at b8:ae:ed:7d:e4:78, length 46

22:53:37.669633 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.100 is-at fc:a6:67:c3:03:8d, length 46

2 devices both replying to the same address